# Authorization request works in Postman but not in React

Tags: reactjs, authentication

To test my already deployed backend, I used Postman. Here I test the `/auth` endpoint with email and password. We use JWT and this is what the request for Postman looks like:

**URL**: `https://<api>/api/auth-service/auth`

**Body (raw/JSON)**: `{"email":"jelle@mail.com","password":"test"}`

The response is a HTTP Status 200 OK with the `Authorization` header containing the Bearer token. However, when I try (seemingly) the same with React using the `fetch` command, it still receives the HTTP Status 200 OK, but without the `Authorization` header.

```js
static async handleSignIn(email, password) {
    let result = null;
    await fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_GATEWAY_URL + "/api/auth-service/auth", {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify({email: email, password: password}),
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "accept": "*/*",
            "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
            "Connection": "keep-alive",
        }
    })
        .then((response) => {
            if (response.headers.get("Authorization") != null) {
                result = response.headers.get("Authorization");
            }
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error);
            throw new Error(error.message)
        });
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the backend, I forgot to expose the Authorization header.

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Authorization
```

In Java Spring Boot you can do that like this:

```java
@Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        final CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("*");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addExposedHeader("Authorization");
        config.addAllowedMethod("OPTIONS");
        config.addAllowedMethod("HEAD");
        config.addAllowedMethod("GET");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PUT");
        config.addAllowedMethod("POST");
        config.addAllowedMethod("DELETE");
        config.addAllowedMethod("PATCH");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        return source;
    }
```

**NOTE:** Allowing all origins and headers might not be the most secure way to go about doing this!